# API HOOKS Windows

Tags: windows, api, hook

I wrote a program using SetWindowsHookEx with WH_CBT hook type in order to intercept every time a gui window is resized and write the string "resized" in a txt file.
But the problem is that when I execute the program one entry of "string" is written and then when I resize other windows, no entries are written.
I provide you with the program and the dll:
program:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    HMODULE hDll = LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Dll1.dll"));
    if (hDll == NULL)
    {
        // Failed to load DLL, handle error
        return 1;
    }

    auto hook = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hDll, "HookProc");
    if (hook == NULL)
    {
        // Failed to get function address, handle error
        FreeLibrary(hDll);
        return 1;
    }

    // Install the hook
    HHOOK hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, hook, hDll, 0);
    if (hHook == NULL)
    {
        // Failed to install the hook, handle error
        FreeLibrary(hDll);
        return 1;
    }

    // Run the message loop

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    // Uninstall the hook when finished
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);

    // Free the DLL
    FreeLibrary(hDll);

    return 0;
}
```

DLL:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h>


extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK HookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HHOOK hHOOK;
    if (nCode == WM_SIZE) {
        // Open file for writing
        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\text.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nullptr, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, nullptr);
     

        // Write "a" to file
        char buffer[] = "resized";
        DWORD dwBytesWritten;
        WriteFile(hFile, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

        // Close file handle
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }

    
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:

        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

I expected every time I resize a window a new entry of  string "resized" would be written

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're going to have to seek to the end of the file before writing. I'm fairly certain that CreateFile doesn't automatically put you at the end. Use SetFilePointer.